# Maintaining a list of regions without overlapps

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I have a list of integer axis aligned cuboids that is being built and then processed (a dirty region system).

Currently this will often have overlaps with some coordinates getting processed many times as a result (although still far less in total than the process everything due to 1 change approach). What I want to do is when adding a new region to the list, is to have a simple way to prevent any such resulting overlaps.

Due to the size of the data (iirc about 100 million cells), even though the coordinates are integers, I want to avoid a bool array of every coordinate to mark it uptodate/dirty. On the other hand, the actual number of regions in the list will generally be pretty small (most of the time only covering a fraction of the data set, with individual regions being 1000's of cells).

```
struct Region
{
    int x, y, z;//corner coordinate
    int w, h, d;//size
};

void addRegion(Region region)
{
    regions.push_back(region);
}
```

So my current thinking is in addRegion to go through all the regions, find the overlapping ones and split them up appropriately. However even in 2D this seems tricky to come up with, so is there a known algorithm for this sort of thing?

Comment: [Quadtrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree#Some_common_uses_of_quadtrees) are supposed to be good for 2D collision detection.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to make use of an [r-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) or r-tree variant, which is designed for indexing multidimensional data and has support for a fast intersection test; and given the size of your dataset, you might instead want to use a [spatial database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database).